# Alter Sql table (Change foreign key to Second primary of the table)

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, alter-table

I've a sql table with a primary key(Auto Incremented) and a foreign key.Now I need to modify the table by modifying the foreign key to second primary key so that its values are not allowed to duplicate.

How do i alter my table without affecting the data? Need the sql code.

Regards,
Vix

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your request, you want to force the foreign key to be unique within the given table so your schema looks like:

```
Create Table Table1
(
    Id int not null primary key clustered
    , ForeignId not null
    , ...
    , Constraint FK_Table1_Table2
        Foreign Key ( ForeignId )
        References Table2( Id )
)
```

And you now want to force ForeignId to be unique in this table, correct? You would do the following:

```
Alter Table Table1
    Add Constraint UC_Table1_ForeignId Unique Nonclustered ( ForeignId )
```

Comment: Yeah.I wanted the foreign key not to be duplicated.